# What does fragmented table mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, fragmentation

I have a MariaDB database with an InnoDB engine and querying data take a lot of time so I search and found that it is maybe related to the tables being fragmented but I cannot understand what it means and what I have to do about it.

Comment: And you ask here because on dba.stackexchange.com you would find real specialists for databases?

Comment: Not likely to be a fragmentation issue.  Show up the query, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and how big the table is.